# How to clear the contents of a file from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a log file that has a bunch of stuff in it that I don't need anymore. I want to clear the contents.

I know how to print the contents to the screen:

```
cat file.log
```

I know how to edit the file, line-by-line:

```
nano file.log
```

But I don't want to delete each line one at a time. Is there a way to do it in one command without destroying the file to do it?

Answer (score 782, accepted):

In bash, just

```
> filename
```

will do. This will leave you with an empty file **filename**.

PS: If you need `sudo` call, please consider to use `truncate` as [answered here](https://superuser.com/a/634217/34893).

Comment: This is probably the raddest command in the history of computing

Comment: On the contrary, @Arekkusandaa.Irujasukin; it works just fine in any version of Windows, so long as, as mentioned, you are using `bash` as your shell and not e. g. `cmd.exe` or PowerShell, neither of which are POSIXy enough to be expected to handle such things.

Comment: LInters complain, maybe more elegant is to `true > filename`

Comment: This is fancy and short, but it does have a couple of downsides. First it's not immediately obvious how to handle file permissions such as the need for `sudo`. Of course you can do it with `sudo bash -c '> filename'`, but spawning a shell is (relatively) expensive. Second it can easily trip up interactive shells that will actually hang waiting for input. This is especially relevant if you want to copy bits of a script into a terminal and get the same results. For these reasons I suggest the [`truncate` based answer](https://superuser.com/a/634217/33767) is actually more robust.

Comment: it does not work in zsh :-(

Answer (score 246):

You can use the user command : truncate

```
truncate -s 0 test.txt
```

("-s 0" to specify the size)

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12/empty-a-file

Comment: Best answer around, works when you're non-root (with sudo) — `sudo echo > file` just gives an error in such cases.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov: `sudo bash -c '> filename'` is how you use the Bash solutions with sudo.

Comment: `brew install truncate` on os x with homebrew installed.

Comment: Works faster than echo

Comment: This also works in a bash script, while `> filename` does not

Comment: This is probably right tool if this is log file. just specifiy filesize limit, have it on cron and be done with it.

Answer (score 64):

```
: > file.log
```

Same as `> filename` in Bash, but works in more shells [(credit)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). Redirects the output from the `true` builtin (which has no output) to `filename`.

Comment: Just do `:> filename`. Doesn't it look like a smiley? :>

Comment: On a macOS, `> filename` freezes. But `: > filename`  works.

Answer (score 58):

You could do this:

```
echo -n "" > file.log
```

Using `>` to write the (null) input from `echo -n` to the file.

Using `>>` would *append* the null input to the file (effectively doing nothing but `touch`ing it).

Comment: This will leave a space in there.

Comment: I'm getting this: -bash:  : command not found

Comment: echo "" > will still give you a file with one character (a newline.) If you want to use echo, use "echo -n > file.log" to echo null.

Comment: It would be better to use a dedicated null-output command like `true` (or its builtin alias `:`), although ultimately you don't need a command at all (see the accepted answer).

Comment: You might have some problems with `sudo`.

Answer (score 17):

Below command should also work :

```
cat /dev/null > file.log
```

Comment: this is what ive been using for many years with no error

Comment: This one should be the best compatible answer because `truncate` isn't built-in in BSD like MacOS and `bash` isn't defult shell for some OS.

Answer (score 16):

ZSH

```
>! filename
```

ZSH will protect users from clobbering files using the io redirect operator `>`. If you use `>!` you can force the truncation of an existing file.

If you want ZSH to use Bash's redirection behavior, were there is no protection from file clobbering, then you need to set the `clobber` option for your shell.

More Info: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html

Answer (score 13):

IF you want to do from inside a vim editor in command line, you can try this:

```
vim file.txt
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
:1,$d
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will find all lines deleted.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for my `maillog`, even `sudo > /var/log/maillog` wouldn't clear it (permission denied)

Comment: @bobobobo It doesn't work as `sudo > /var/log/maillog` means - run sudo, and put its output into the file. Obviously it puts output with current user permissions. Easier thing do `sudo su` to start root shell and then do `> /var/log/maillog`.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ rm file.log; touch file.log
```

or

```
$ cat > file.log
```

followed by `control-d`.

or...or...or...

Ah. Here is a single command version:

```
$ dd if=/dev/null of=file.log
```

Comment: Thechickenmoo's suggestion of `echo "" > file.log` is better than the `cat` option you show, in this situation, tho there are others where `cat` is more appropriate.  both use the same shell redirection to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You dont need to run the cat command. Just "> file.log" will do it.

Comment: Removing the file will reset the creation date.

Comment: Removing the file will cause programs watching that file to lose their pointer to it (i.e., it will have a new address in the filesystem). 

Generally speaking, yes `rm` will accomplish the task of producing an empty file with the same name. But it's not going to be right for every use case.

Comment: +1 for Robert. The rm way is useless in case you have a process writing into the file, while you want this truncation look unnoticed for this process.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to sudo to superuser privilege to access the file then the accepted answer will not work. Using this does work:

```
truncate -s0 file
```

or explicitly with sudo:

```
sudo truncate -s0 file
```

More info here http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12/empty-a-file

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using `sed`

`sed -i d filename`

Comment: +1. and you can do also with `awk` but this will be too slow for large files.

Comment: @Cuauhtli, why would it be slow?

Answer (score 2):

Few alternatives:

```
ex +%d -scwq file.log
cp /dev/null file.log
vi +%d -escwq file.log
install -m600 /dev/null file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have multiple files you can use the following:

```
for file in /path/to/file/*; do > $file; done
```

This is helpful for log files in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have spaces in filenames, use:

```
for file in /path/to/file/*; do > "$file"; done
```

(I could not to include it in comments to previous answer because I don't have 50 reputation. Sometimes limitations are contra productive.)

Answer (score 1):

With my permissions this is the only thing that worked:

```
touch temp.txt
sudo mv temp.txt original-file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to clear the file as listed below:

```
echo "" > filename
cat /dev/null > filename
```

Below examples are mostly used in shell scripting

```
just# > filename
: > filename
```

Answer (score 0):

One line at a time?

Try vi(m), the lovely text editor that can do anything.
In this case, navigate to a line, press d (for delete), and d again (for line).

Comment: If you want to get rid of the whole file in vim, with the cursor at the top of the document, typing d G (that's d, then shift-G) will delete the entire file (d for delete, G for end of the file).  I prefer your method, though (it gives me more time to think about whether or not I REALLY want to trash the file).

Comment: @Babu `gg` moves to the top so the entire sequence could be `ggdG`.

Answer (score 0):

In windows environment:

```
type nul >filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat filename
cp filename filename.bak
cat /dev/null > test
```

This will empty the original file and but you can still access the backup if you need the old contents of the file

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.